# Unite column names

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to unite all columns of the dataframe `df` separating them with `|`.

However, for the name of the new column I would like to have all column names merged together separated the same way (eg S_n|S_s|S_b).

Here is what I tried and received error message  `Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument`

```
S_n = c(2, 3, 5) 
S_s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
S_b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(S_n, S_s, S_b)
unite(df, S_n|S_s|S_b, sep="|", remove=TRUE)
```

Comment: `unite(df, "S_n|S_s|S_b", sep="|", remove=TRUE)`. You need quotes around the column name because it's a non-standard name. (Standard names can't contain symbols other than `.` and `_`).

Comment: what package is `unite()` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unite(df, "S_n|S_s|S_b", sep="|", remove=TRUE)`. You need quotes around the column name because it's a non-standard name. (Standard names can't contain symbols other than `.` and `_`).

Answer (score 1):

One idea via base R can be,

```
df[paste(names(df), collapse = '|')] <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep = '|'))


#  S_n S_s   S_b S_n|S_s|S_b
#1   2  aa  TRUE   2|aa|TRUE
#2   3  bb FALSE  3|bb|FALSE
#3   5  cc  TRUE   5|cc|TRUE
```